# Java clear the List if all elements are zero

Tags: java, list

I have List. This will be returned part of web service response. I want clear the list if all the values in the list are zero.

I have did with below code to achieve. But i'm looking for better solution.

```
i=0;
for (int element : myList) {
   if (element != 0)
        break;
    else
        i++;
}
if (myList.size()==i)
      myList.clear();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review questions should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com (but read their [guidance](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first).

Comment: Code review is off-topic?  What is on-topic here then?

Comment: You don't need a counter at all: http://pastie.org/10885495 Or you could do it with more overhead but possibly less code with Java 8 streams (certainly fewer lines, but whether that really translates into *less code* is another thing).

Comment: @MrSmith: [This stuff](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could invert the count to make it somewhat simpler

```
int zero_elements = 0;
for (int element : myList) {
  if (element == 0) zero_elements++;
}
if (myList.size() == zero_elements) myList.clear();
```

To take it one step further you can use Collections.frequency() like so

```
if (Collections.frequency(myList, 0) == myList.size())
  myList.clear();
```

If your willing to add a library and Java 8, a third option would be to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java) like so

```
if (Iterables.all(myList, (int element) -> element == 0))
    myList.clear();
```

Comment: You could also use streams: if(myList.parallelStream().allMatch(i -> i == 0)) myList.clear();

Comment: Collections.frequency method seems interesting. I will try it.

Comment: @HariM I added an example using Guava as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the duplicate values then simply check that the list only contains 1 value, equaled to 0:

```
Set<Integer> noDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>(myList);
if (noDuplicates.size() == 1 && noDuplicates.iterator().next() == 0) {
    myList.clear();
}
```

Comment: why the downvote ? I believe this solution works well, and the code is clean

Comment: Agreed; this is how I'd do it.

Comment: Using a set potentially creates a full copy of the list (if every item is unique in itself). You always check the full list even if the first item is not "0". Your approach is only decent if the "all items are zero"-case is the expected. There are just much better approaches (even the original is better).

Comment: @Alex it just seemed like a very counter intuitive way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Lambdas, then you can use the [Collections#frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) class, get the frequency of the zero element in the list and if the frequency is the same as the list sizes then you clear it...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(0);
myList.add(0);
myList.add(0);
myList.add(0);
myList.add(0);
// 5 elements all zeros

int occurrences = Collections.frequency(myList, 0);
if (occurrences == myList.size()) {
    myList.clear();
}

// 
// using Lambdas:
boolean areAllZero = myList.parallelStream().allMatch(i -> i == 0);
if (areAllZero) {
    myList.clear();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would go with:

```
private void clearIfContainsOnlyZeros(List<Integer> list){
    for(int value:list){
        if (value !=0){
            return;
        }
    }
    list.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java 8 Streams API for this...

```
if (myList.stream().filter(i -> i != 0).count() == 0) {
    myList.clear();
}
```

Checking for any non-zero values and getting a count. If the count of non zero values is zero, then they all must be zero. Hence, clear the list.

**Or, better still**...

```
if (myList.stream().allMatch(i -> i == 0)) {
    myList.clear();
}
```

Also... (given k5_'s comment below)...

```
if (!myList.stream().filter(i -> i != 0).findFirst().isPresent()) {
    myList.clear();
}
```

Comment: .findFirst().absent() would be a better check and avoid the complete scan

Comment: Actually, one would assume `allMatch` is lazy.

Comment: allMatch is also lazy. My comment was meant for the count version wich is not lazy.

Comment: It has the tersest syntax though and it is quite clear in its logic from an clarity context, so it's up to the OP what suits his purposes best with regards to efficiency, maintainability, etc.

Comment: ... or f(!myList.stream().anyMatch(i -> i != 0)) myList.clear();

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion but I don't think its an advisable approach but you can have a try on it.
You can have a flag that is initialized to some value initially and every time the list is cleared and whenever an item is added to or removed from the list, then based on the item's value the flag value will be changed accordingly.

For example, you can have a variable `flag` whose value is initially 0. When you insert an item into the list, (you'll have to write a separate block, maybe a method, to insert items into the list so as to check the value of the item and make changes to the flag) there is a check on the item's value and if the value is 0, then `flag` is changed to 1. You can avoid the above loop to clear the list.